# Visual Studio Team Services and delete file (task build) with exclude folder

Tags: build, pattern-matching, azure-devops

I am issue with delete-files task in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online, TFS Online):

https://www.visualstudio.com/it-it/docs/build/steps/utility/delete-files

I need delete all files and folders (recursively) except one folder (App_Data).

I am trying:

`**\!(App_Data\*) or **\!(App_Data)`

This pattern almost works. Only delete all files in App_Data.

So my question is simple - How is pattern to delete all files and folders except one?

Thanks

Comment: Are there many App_Data folders in Source folder? If not, you can use !(App_Data)

Comment: Yep, there is some folder and subfolder in App_Data ...

Comment: What's the structure of folders?

Comment: Can you share the structure of these folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For some reason the original answer was about test pattern, not a delete pattern..**

For the delete pattern i think it should be the following:

```
**;!App_data\*
```

For that second @Saad Awan that would be:

```
**;!**\bin\*;!**\report\*
```

Comment: What is `:-`? I cannot find any documentation about this.

Comment: @NP83, I have also the same problem i need/keep only 2 folders and reset need to deleted, i tried many minipattrren but not succeed                                    (bin) (report) folders need to be keep